# Separate php strings with comma

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
<li class="company-address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $user_meta['company'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['address_1'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['address_2'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['city'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['postcode'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['state'][0]; ?> <?php echo $user_meta['country'][0]; ?></li>
```

How do I add a comma behind each php string except the last one to get a following output ?? :

> company, address 1, address 2, city, postcode, state, country

Comment: why dont you echo the string.... also you dont need to keep opening and closing the php brackets, open them , echo everything then close them. its overkill

Comment: @NoLiver92 How do I do that ? Sorry, not an expert on php. And please don't downvote me if you find it a silly question, I really don't know php much, learning, thanks

Comment: You wont have been downvoted because of its a silly question. you would have been downvoted because what you have asked is answered many times before and if you searched your title in google there are many answers

Comment: @NoLiver92 That's correct, I found a few answers however not knowing php much I wasn't able to fit the answers into my own case, that's why I asked again to give my code.

Comment: If you dont know much php why dont you learn it through sites like thenewboston which explain what it all does before undertaking a php task

Comment: I'd like to combine the theory with the practice. That's why I'm undertaking a php task. Not for a client or anybodY, just for my self to practice on.

Comment: @NoLiver92 Dude, thenewboston.com ? WTF ? I might not know anything about PHP, that's true, but I know quite a bit about web marketing. If this is your site, then let me tell you that it is so busy trying to do everything and anything that I have no idea what is going on there. I think you should concentrate on whatever you know the best. I will definitely not learn an PHP from here..

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this. One is :

```
$result = array();
foreach($user_meta as $data){
    $result[] = $data[0];
}
echo implode(', ' $result);
```

Another is :

```
$result = "";
foreach($user_meta as $data){
    if($result != "")
        $result .= ", ";
    $result .= $data[0];
}
echo $result;
```

For a ordered version :

```
$order = array('company', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city', 'postcode', 'state', 'country');
$result = array();
foreach($order as $elem){
    if($user_meta[$elem][0] != "")
        $result[] = $user_meta[$elem][0];
}
echo implode(', ', $result);
```

Comment: this is a clean approach.  but doesn't take into account any  ordering needs.

Comment: I added a ordering version ;) 
Thank you for the comment !

Comment: @Spoke44 I have a question. I implemented the latest solution ( #3 ) you posted. The problem is that it still shows the commas even if the field is not filed in. So for example if only one field out of all is filled in, my output looks like ,,,City,,,
How can I display the comma only after a valid input ?

Comment: @Spoke44 Thanks a lot. That works great now. I'm not able to vote due to my low reputation score yet, but many thanks, you're a legend ..

Answer (score 1):

you just might want to give sprintf() a try.

```
$x = sprintf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", $user_meta['company'][0],$user_meta['address_1'][0], $user_meta['address_2'][0], $user_meta['city'][0], $user_meta['postcode'][0], $user_meta['state'][0],$user_meta['country'][0]);

echo $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To put a , in your code, Change it to this below. it neatens up your code, no need for multiple php brackets etc, just make it one instance. There are other ways but it will depend on what is in the $user_meta variable.

```
<li class="company-address">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 
<?php 
  echo $user_meta['company'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['address_1'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['address_2'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['city'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['postcode'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['state'][0];
  echo ", ";
  echo $user_meta['country'][0]; 
?></li>
```

Comment: Your code is not great btw. If the user only fills in one field out of all and leave the rest blank, it will still create commas.

Comment: You will then have to add in if statements to check if the fields are set then echo the field and commas if they are.